# Во всех отелях "Группы(а) Отелей Евразия"

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение

Как правильно - купоны действуют во всех отелях "Группы(а) Отелей Евразия"?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятен вопрос. Речь идет о названии? Это  "ГруппА отелей Евразия" или "ГруппЫ отелей Евразия"?  Или группа отелей "Евразия" (названием является только последнее слово? Уточните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Надюшка! Название-"Группа Отелей Евразия".!Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение! 
Мне кажется, что лучше "Купоны действуют во всех отелях сети "Группа отелей Евразия". Но мне не нравится повторение слова "отели". Лучше как-то заменить, если смысл не пострадает.